# Custom Post Types,Permalink and Heirarchy

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

Basicly I want to indroduce a custom heirarchy with custom post types.
I Would like it to be like this.

The Main Brands URL : `http://localhost/brands/` which lists different types of Brands.

The personal Brand URL : `http://localhost/brands/nike` which displays overview of brand `"nike"` andlinks to  different post types made by that particular Brand Account.

The Brand Gallery URL : `http://localhost/brands/nike/gallery` which is the archive page for custom post type `"Gallery"`.

The Gallery URL : 'http://localhost/brands/nike/gallery/posttitle`which displays the custom post tupe`"gallery"`.

Similarly with custom post type `"Information"` and `"Brochure"` the links should be `http://localhost/brands/nike/information/posttitle` and `http://localhost/brands/nike/brochure/posttitle`.

I have Implemented the basic structure for permalink of custom post type but have not figured out how to develop the archive page.

I would like to know how to implement the acrhive page - `http://localhost/brands/` and `http://localhost/brands/nike`.

Below is the code for permalink of custom Post type `"gallery"`.

```
  add_action('init', 'tdd_add_rewrite_rules');
  function tdd_add_rewrite_rules(){
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag('%brand_name%', '([^/]+)', '');
    $wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('gallery', '/brands/%brand_name%/gallery/%gallery%', false);
  }

  add_filter('post_type_link', 'tdd_permalinks', 10, 3); 
  function tdd_permalinks($permalink, $post, $leavename){ 
    $no_data = get_the_author_meta('ID');;
    $post_id = $post->ID;
    if($post->post_type != 'gallery' || empty($permalink) || in_array($post->post_status, array('draft', 'pending', 'auto-draft'))) return $permalink;
    $var1 = get_the_author_meta('brand_name');

  $var1 = sanitize_title($var1);
  if(!$var1) { $var1 = $no_data; }

  $permalink = str_replace('%brand_name%', $var1, $permalink); 
  return $permalink; 
  }
```

Comment: In your CPT creation you need to have `'has_archive' => true` set for archives to work. Then you make the template `archive-posttype.php` where posttype is the name of the post type.

Comment: @Aibrean yes i have done it....but the permalink is `http://localhost/gallery/[gallery_name]` and i want it in the form of `http://localhost/hotel/[hotel_name]/gallery/[gallery_name]`

Comment: More over i want to create a new archive page on the link `http://localhost/hotel/[hotel_name]` where `[hotel_name]` is usermeta and is unique for each user.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was solved with [this link](http://www.rlmseo.com/blog/passing-get-query-string-parameters-in-wordpress-url/). It was very helpful and difficult to find.

```
function add_custom_query_var( $vars ){
  $vars[] = "brand_name";
  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_custom_query_var' );

function add_rewrite_rules($aRules) {
$aNewRules = array('brand/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=hotel&brand_name=$matches[1]');
$aRules = $aNewRules + $aRules;
return $aRules;
}
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'add_rewrite_rules');
```